# How to have a Reporting Services parameter automatically selected if there is only one

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm using SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) developed in Visual Studio 2010 to build my reports.

If there is only one item in a report parameter drop-down then I would like that item automatically selected. Instead of getting *Select a Value* and then having to manually a select that item (when it's the only one in the list).

At the moment, I deal with this by having the default value of the report parameter set by a stored procedure that checks the row count of the items in the parameter list and returns a default if there is only one. But this seems like overkill.

Is there a way I can set this in Reporting Services?

Comment: It's not an option to always select the first value, even if there are more options?

Comment: I think your current solution is the best option. It's the one I would use.

Comment: @Jeroen If it was an option (I'm not sure), how would I do that in SSRS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I'm going to do this with a stored procedure (the way I'm doing it now): 
[MSDN Answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/e2eb17cb-abce-4d9c-aca1-c56d8ad40967)